# Python how to turn a result of a method into generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I have the following inheritance:

```
class Processor(object):
    def get_listings(self):
        """
        returns a list of data
        """
        raise NotImplemented()

    def run(self):
        for listing in get_listings():
           do_stuff(listing)

class DBProcessor(Processor):
    def get_listings(self):
        """
        return a large set of paginated data
        """
        ...
        for page in pages:
            for data in db.fetch_from_query(...):
                yield data
```

Although this works, this fails on `len(self.get_listings())` or any other list operations.

My question is how to refactor my code that `DBProcessor.get_listings` can handle list operations, but also when it's iterator called it will return a generator?

Answer (score 4):

I think I got an idea:

```
class DBListings(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for page in pages:
            for data in db.fetch_from_query(...):
                yield data

    def __len__(self):
        return db.get_total_from_query(...)
        """
        Or the following
        counter = 0
        for x in self:
           counter += 1
        return counter
        """

class DBProcessor(Processor):
    def get_listings(self):
        """
        return a large set of paginated data
        """
        return DBListings()
```

**UPDATE**: Just tested the above code, works.

Comment: `sum(1 for _ in self)` would do the same. What does `db.fetch_from_query` return?

Comment: return a list of rows from database

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which `list`-operations you want to support. Some of them will *only* consume the generator when defaulting to `iter`.

If you know the result of the operation (for example `len`) beforehand you can just bypass it by creating a GeneratorContainer:

```
class GeneratorContainer():
    def __init__(self, generator, length):
        self.generator = generator
        self.length = length

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.generator

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

result = GeneratorContainer(DBProcessor().get_listings(), length) 
# But you need to know the length-value.
```

Calling `len` will then not try to iterate over the generator. But you can always just create a list so that the data will not be exhausted:

```
result = list(DBProcessor().get_listings())
```

and use it as a list without the generator advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert the generator (iterator in non-Python speak) produced by `get_listings` to a list, simply use

```
listings = list(get_listings())
```